# Tabulator not working because of a missing library, is there any issue?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, tabulator

I have been trying to resolve the issue with Tabulator for quite long, but I keep getting the same error not sure what is going wrong. Is there a library I am missing?

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tabulator is not a function

<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.0.4/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.0.4/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/4.0.5/css/tabulator.min.css" >
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/4.0.5/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/4.0.5/js/tabulator_core.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/4.0.5/js/modules/format.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

```
$("#example-table").tabulator({
height:"311px",
columns:[
    {title:"Name", field:"name"},
    {title:"Progress", field:"progress", sorter:"number"},
    {title:"Gender", field:"gender"},
    {title:"Rating", field:"rating"},
    {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col"},
    {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", align:"center"},
    ]
});

var tabledata = [
    {id:1, progress:"Oli Bob", gender:"12", rating:"red",col:"10", dob:""}];

//load sample data into the table
//table.setData(tabledata);
$("#example-table").tabulator("setData", tabledata);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this library provide jquery plugin. but according to documentation of this library below code is working.

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height: "311px",
    columns: [
        { title: "Name", field: "name" },
        { title: "Progress", field: "progress", sorter: "number" },
        { title: "Gender", field: "gender" },
        { title: "Rating", field: "rating" },
        { title: "Favourite Color", field: "col" },
        { title: "Date Of Birth", field: "dob", align: "center" },
    ]      
});

var tabledata = [
    { id: 1, name:"Oli", progress: "Oli Bob", gender: "12", rating: "red", col: "10", dob: "" }];

table.setData(tabledata);
```

Comment: I am facing an issue saying that #example-table is not available

Comment: You have to declare div tag in HTMl with id = "example-table"

Answer (score 1):

As of version 4.0 Tabulator is not dependent on jQuery, you only have to to include it if you want to use the jQuery wrapper or are using version 3.5 or earlier.

The [Quickstart Guide](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/quickstart) takes you through how to setup a basic example.

once you have included the source files:

```
<link href="dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
```

you need to create a div to hold the table:

```
<div id="example-table"></div>
```

define an array of data:

```
var tabledata = [
    {id:1, name:"Oli Bob", age:"12", col:"red", dob:""},
    {id:2, name:"Mary May", age:"1", col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982"},
    {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", age:"42", col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982"},
    {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", age:"125", col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980"},
    {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", age:"16", col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999"},
];
```

Then create your table:

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height:205, // set height of table (in CSS or here), this enables the Virtual DOM and improves render speed dramatically (can be any valid css height value)
    data:tabledata, //set the table data
    layout:"fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
    columns:[ //Define Table Columns
        {title:"Name", field:"name", width:150},
        {title:"Age", field:"age", align:"left", formatter:"progress"},
        {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col"},
        {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", sorter:"date", align:"center"},
    ],
    rowClick:function(e, row){ //trigger an alert message when the row is clicked
        alert("Row " + row.getData().id + " Clicked!!!!");
    },
});
```